# Powershell where filter not working

Tags: powershell, filter, powershell-2.0

I have the following simple code:

```
remove-item -path $path | where($_ -like "*IE*")
```

But for some reason I get an error due to the wildcards

Comment: "An" error? You don't know which one? Or it literally says "there is an error", no further indication of what is wrong?

Comment: What's in the $Path Variable? You also made an error with the "Where" filter, you have to place it between curly braces "{}" instead of normal ones "()"

Comment: BTW, `Remove-Item` does not output any objects for `Where-Object` to filter.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense in its current form. What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your script above has a few errors. I'll try to help you out with them.

First and foremost, the Remove-Item cmdlet doesn't provide any output for your where line. You've got to get it first. I'm going to assume since you want to filter out items that don't match IE, you're getting multiple files from a directory. If this is only a single file, all you need to do is Remove-Item -Path $Path. If it's a directory, the cmdlet is Get-ChildItem

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path
```

Now that you have all of your items from $Path, we need to filter them. You do this with Where-Object. Like this...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | Where-Object
```

This is where the next issue comes in. You are using -like when I think you want -match. Also, your $_ is going to signify the entire object. We need to match a property of the object. It'd look like this

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.PROPERTYNAME -match "IE"}
```

Now that we have our objects, and we have them sorted, it's time to remove them. We do this using the Remove-Item cmdlet, from above. Please notice that this time, it's at the end of the pipeline, rather than the beginning.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.PROPERTYNAME -match "IE"} | Remove-Item
```

If you don't want to confirm each and every one (and you're sure these are the items you want to remove), add -Confirm:$false after Remove-Item. Otherwise, you'll have to confirm in the console every file you want to remove.

I really hope this helps!